# How to count the number of leaves of a plant with this fold function?

Tags: haskell, tree, fold

Color and Plant are datatypes, defined like this:

```
data Color = Red | Pink | White | Blue | Purple | Green | Yellow
   deriving (Show, Eq)

data Plant=
      Leaf
   |  Blossom Color
   |  Stalk Plant Plant
   deriving (Show, Eq)
```

The fold function is this:

```
fold_plant :: (x -> x -> x) -> (Color -> x) -> x -> Plant -> x
fold_plant s b l = fold_plant'
    where fold_plant' Leaf = l
          fold_plant' (Blossom c) = b c
          fold_plant' (Stalk lef rig) = s (fold_plant' lef) (fold_plant' right)
```

Now I'm supposed to implement a function `amount` which makes use of the fold function, takes a `Plant` as argument and returns the amount of leaves in the plant.
The main problem I think I'm facing right now is that the fold function I'm supposed to use doesn't work like the usual fold functions. By that I mean like `foldr` and `foldl`, since those take 3 arguments: a function, an initial value and a list. But in my function `fold_plant` there's just none of that.

This is what I thought about using but I think I don't understand everything correctly.

```
amount :: Plant-> Integer
amount input = length . filter (Leaf ==) fold_plant Stalk Blossom Leaf input
```

Comment: FWIW, `fold_plant` *is* equivalent to `foldr`.  Both of them are the catamorphism for their type. You can think of a catamorphism in a couple different ways. One, it's a conversion from a data structure to its Church-encoded form. Alternatively, it's a function that takes takes an argument that describes how to convert each constructor to an arbitrary result type (with some cleverness in handling recursion).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answer jumps straight to the solution, then defends that solution as the correct one. In this answer, I'd like to go the other direction: to describe a method by which you can invent the solution yourself.

I will assume that you could yourself have first written this function *without* the fold, just with basic pattern matching and recursion. Here's what you might have come up with (modulo some naming, perhaps):

```
amount Leaf = 1
amount (Blossom c) = 0
amount (Stalk lef rig) = amount lef + amount rig
```

Now compare with this simplified definition of the fold (which doesn't use a `where`-block helper function):

```
fold_plant s b l Leaf = l
fold_plant s b l (Blossom c) = b c
fold_plant s b l (Stalk lef rig) = s (fold_plant s b l lef) (fold_plant s b l rig)
```

My goodness those two definitions look similar! Let's hypothesize that `amount = fold_plant s b l` for some choices of `s`, `b`, and `l`. Looking at the first two equations:

```
amount           Leaf = 1
fold_plant s b l Leaf = l
```

So we should choose `l = 1`. For the second two equations:

```
amount           (Blossom c) = 0
fold_plant s b l (Blossom c) = b c
```

So we should choose `b c = 0`. And the last two equations:

```
amount           (Stalk lef rig) = amount lef + amount rig
fold_plant s b l (Stalk lef rig) = s (fold_plant s b l lef) (fold_plant s b l rig)
```

Well, recall our hypothesis is that `amount = fold_plant s b l`, so

```
s (fold_plant s b l lef) (fold_plant s b l rig) = s (amount lef) (amount rig)
```

and the two equations are now:

```
amount           (Stalk lef rig) = amount lef + amount rig
fold_plant s b l (Stalk lef rig) = s (amount lef) (amount rig)
```

So we should choose `s x y = x + y`. Writing down these equations all at once, we have arrived at our answer:

```
amount = fold_plant s b l where
    l = 1
    b c = 0
    s x y = x + y
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I understood now. For example if I wanted to add every color of every blossom to a list could I just write `colors = fold_plant (++) Color _`?

Comment: @dYTe Try it and see! And if that function doesn't work the way you thought it would, do try arriving at that answer the long way -- by writing down the function explicitly, and slowly (as in this answer) working out what `s`, `b`, and `l` should be by comparing the definition of your function with the definition of the fold. You will, with practice, be able to do that in your head, but the way you get good practice is by doing it slowly and carefully.

Comment: @dYTe now compare the last definition in this answer with the `reduction_step` in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44927473/849891) to your previous question on the subject. they match verbatim. the `r` in `Result r` stands for "number of leaves" now. so `s` combines the two recursive results, `l` and `b` convert the result in non-recursive case (i.e., base case).

Comment: @WillNess Yikes. Now that I see that this is the latest in a chain of questions, I'm beginning to worry we're depriving dYTe of his homework. =/

Comment: While I didn't expect a complete solution to the question, I still was able to fully understand how everything works now. I was also able to finish all the other exercises now thanks to you, so you actually made it possible for me to not just finish everything but to also actually understand what I'm doing. Thanks again.

Comment: @dYTe I'm really happy to hear that, thanks for letting us know! That's very reassuring, and I wish you continued success.

Answer (score 3):

No, the idea is usually **to use the `fold_plant`** as a way to count the number of leaves. You can do this with:

```
amount :: Num n => Plant -> n
amount = fold_plant (+) (const 0) 1
```

So that means that:

- for every `Stalk x y`, we fold it and return the *sum* of the number of leaves of the two children;
- for every `Blossom x`, we return `0` (since we call `const 0` on the color `x`, and `const 0` returns `0` on every input); and
- for every `Leaf`, we return a `1`.

So since every leave is mapped on `1`, every `Blossom` on `0`, and the `Stalk` works as an addition `(+)` operator, we obtain the total number of leaves.